# cotangent and tangent space

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, hamilton-equations

In most books of mechanics, if we study a mechanical system on a Manifold $M$, an Hamiltonian is a function 
$$
H:TM\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$
$$
(q,p) \mapsto H(q,p)
$$

This I understand, if $M=\mathbb{R}^3$ then $TM=\mathbb{R}^3\times \mathbb{R}^3$ and $q$ the position is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $p$ the momentum is a vector of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

However we can also find that $(q,p)$ are local coordinates on $T^\ast M$.
I also understand this, in the sense that if $F$ is a vector field, then p acts on $F(q)$ : $p\cdot F(q)$, or also that the Hamiltonian lift of the vector field $F$ is $p\cdot F$.

What is right or wrong in a general sense ? 
Are these difference important ?

Comment: Momentum is usually viewed as a coordinate on the cotangent bundle. Velocity is the coordinate on the tangent bundle.

Comment: so it's just a convention ? 
the momentum $p = m \dot q$ is usually in $T_q^\ast M$ and $\dot q$ is in $T_q M$ ?

Comment: well velocities are naturally associated with derivations, and the derivative of the Hamiltonian (a scalar function) is naturally viewed as a 1-form. Is it _just_ a convention? I dunno. Certainly in the presence of a metric there's not much distinction. Your last sentence correctly describes the natural distinction though.

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake. The reason canonical momenta are naturally viewed as 1-forms is not that $dH$ is a 1-form, although that sounds plausible since its coordinate components are $\partial H\over\partial q$. But $dH$ is a 1-form on $T^\ast M$, whereas $p$ is a 1-form on $M$.

Comment: A better explanation is just to observe that whatever compatible coordinates you choose on the cotangent bundle, they obey the equations of canonical momenta.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. In Hamiltonian mechanics we work on **co**tangent bundle of $M$ because it provide nice geometric theory, namely $T^*M$ has natural symplectic structure, and $p, q$ playing symmetric roles here. Moreover, we can forget about $M$ and just study abstract even-dimensional manifolds with symplectic form on it.